# How to make <select> <option> related to another <select>'s <option>?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms, select

I'm working on a form. There are select elements and their options are from a database.

When i choose the first (for example a school class) the second have to show only those names who are in the class selected at first, from database too.

I'm rookie at Javascript and JQuery so I'm okay with page refreshing PHP solutions but I can't figure it out on my own. Can you please give me some instructions or advices how to start to work on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with ajax using preferably jquery and json.

javascript/ajax:

```
function fillSecondSelect()
{
    $.get("ajaxFill.php?id=" + $("#class").val(),"",function(data) {
        var selectData = "<option value=''> - Choose Student - </option>";
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            selectData += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $("#students").html(selectData);
    });
}
```

html:

```
<select id="class" name="class" onchange="fillSecondSelect()">
<option value=""> - Choose Class - </option>
<option value='1'>Class A</option>
<option value='2'>Class B</option>
</select>

<select id="students" name="students"></select>
```

ajaxFill.php (which should get the student data according the class id sent from mysql and serve it as JSON):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE class_id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $students[] = array("id" => $row['student_id'], "name" => $row['student_name']);
}

echo json_encode($students);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use Jquery and Ajax to fetch the Students in a class based on the Class selected and load the student list into a Select element without refreshing the page.

HTML

```
<select id="selectedclass" onBlur="loadstudent();">
    <option>class 1</option>
    <option>class 2</option>
    <option>class 1</option>
</select>

 <select id="students" ></select>
```

Javascript

```
  function loadstudent(){


 var selectedclass = $('selectedclass').val();//user id


$.ajax({

   type:'POST',
   url: your php script,
   data: 'selectedclass='+selectedclass,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data)          
  {

    var classlist='', html;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        classlist = data[i];
                    html+=classlist.students

    }
        //get number of outbox
            $('#students').html(html);  


  },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

            alert('Error');

    }
});
```

}

PHP

```
 <?php

   include "config.php";//database connection file

  //database using PDO
  $db = pdoDB::getConnection();

  //data from html
  $student_class=$_POST['selectedclass'];

   $query = "SELECT student_lastName,student_firstName
        FROM student_table WHERE student_class='student_class'"; 

   $result   = $dbase->query($query) or die("failed!");

  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){


    //credits info
    $studentlist="<option>".$row['student_lastName']." ".$row['student_firstName']."</option>";



   $results[] = array("students"=>$studentlist);


 }

  header('Content-type:application/json');
   exit (json_encode($results)); 



?>
```

The data sent from the PHP script should be encoded with JSON

Answer (score 0):

Modern websites use ajax to do this.

After the first item is selected an ajax request is sent which delivers the data for the second select.

There are many ways to build the second select. The ajax response could contain a json array with all the data and then you build the select field with js.

Or the response delivers complete html and all you have to do is to insert it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is exactly that you mean: http://codepen.io/man/pen/oBFlE

Put the js code in your file. You can have as many levels as you want. Explaining:

```
<select name="level1"><!--this is the "main" select-->
<option value="level2A">Level2A</option>
<option value="level2A">Level2B</option>
</select>
<select name="level2A"><!--this shows when the user selects the option with name ""level2A"-->
<option value="level3"></option>
</select>
<select name="level2B">
<!--options...-->
</select>
<select name="level3"></select>
```

Comment: "//" is not comment in html. you should use <!-- --> instead, which I fixed in your answer

Comment: Yes, but `//` is faster to write